# Passing an array to a function and then changing the values?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

Basically, let's say I declare an array in int main() and then pass it to another function, can i then change what values the array holds? Something like:

```
int main()
{
  myarray[3] = {4, 5, 6};

  myfunc(myarray);

 return 0;
}

int myfunc(int myarray[])
{
  int x
  cout << "Choose a number";
  cin >> x

  if (x == 1)
   {
     myarray[] = {0, 1, 3}
   } 
  else
   {
     some code
   }

return 6;
}
```

This code obviously does not compile, but I can't really think of any other ways to change the values in the array within the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify elements in the array however initializer lists like this:

```
myarray[] = {0, 1, 3}
```

can only be used when you declare the array. To assign to the array you will have to assign each element individually:

```
myarray[0] = 0;
myarray[1] = 1;
myarray[2] = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the existing function signature there's no way to safely change the values. Normally you 'd do something like

```
myarray[0] = 0;
myarray[1] = 1;
//etc
```

There are many other ways to approach this as well, depending on how the values to go into the array are stored (either [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) or [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) might be handy here). But right now you don't have a way to know where the array ends.

To amend this, you need to pass the length of the array to the function somehow. One way is to simply pass an additional `size_t length` parameter. An arguably better way that works in the spirit of C++ iterators is to write the signature like

```
int myfunc(int* begin, int* end);
```

and call it with something like

```
myarray[3] = {4, 5, 6};
myfunc(myarray, myarray + sizeof(myarray) / sizeof(myarray[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x == 1)
{
  myarray[] = {0, 1, 3}  // {0,1,3} is an initializer list.
}
```

Initializer lists are allowed only at the point of declaration. They are not allowed in assignments. And in the if statement, you are doing an assignment. The only way of modifying the array elements is by changing element at each index in the `if`.

```
myarray[0] = 0;
myarray[1] = 1;
myarray[2] = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This: `myarray[] = {0, 1, 3}` - is wrong.

You should pass the length of the array, and run a loop that would change its values, instead.

You should never assume a size of the array you get in a function. If the size is constant - make it `myfunc(int myarray[THE_SIZE])`, otherwise it has to be `myfunc(int myarray[], int size)`, where `size` is the size of the array passed.